# dotnet pack ouput and Visual Studio's local package source

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-core

I am trying to use `dotnet pack` to create NuGet package and copy it to the NuGet packages folder used as NuGet source in Visual Studio. Before `dotnet` I used `dnu pack` for creating NuGet packages. This command created folder with project version with `lib` folder, `.nuspec`, `.nupkg` and `.nupkg.sha512` files.

When `dotnet` was introduced, I migrated to it and after packing I got only two files, `.nupkg` and `.symbols.nupkg`. If I copy it to folder used in visual studio as NuGet source, they are not recognised.

What am I missing? I am currently using version 1.0.0-preview3-003171 of .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I handle packages locally in my development environment:

**Step 1**: Set up a local NuGet source. You need a copy of the [NuGet CLI](http://dist.nuget.org/index.html) if you don't already have it. Follow the instructions on [creating a local NuGet feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#creating-local-feeds-v3.3+): basically, create an empty folder. I chose `C:\Users\Nate\Documents\LocalNuget`.

**Step 2**: Add packages to the local source with `nuget add [file] -source [folder]`. I added an environment variable called `local_nuget_path` that pointed to the folder so I wouldn't have to type it all the time:

```
> setx local_nuget_path "C:\Users\<you>\Documents\LocalNuget"
```

For even more convenience, I wrote a simple PowerShell cmdlet to add packages automatically:

**nuget-functions.ps1**

```
Function Nuget-AddLocal {
  Param([string]$file)
  nuget add $file -Source $env:local_nuget_path
}

Function Nuget-AddAllLocal {
  Param([string]$path)

  Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter *.nupkg | `
  Foreach-Object {
    Nuget-AddLocal $_.FullName
  }
}
```

Add this to your PowerShell profile so it is available in every console window:

```
> notepad $profile
```

Add this line to `profile.ps1` (substituting the real path of the file):

```
. C:\Users\<you>\Documents\nuget-functions.ps1
```

**Step 3**: Add the local source to NuGet as a feed.

```
> nuget sources add -Name Local -Source $env:local_nuget_path
```

**Step 4:** Profit!

Produce packages and add them to your local source in two simple steps:

```
> dotnet pack
> Nuget-AddAllLocal
```